# Конструктор копирования не работает должным образом в этом коде. Почему?

Tags: c++

В приведённом примере несмотря на наличие конструктора копирования и перегруженного оператора присваивания программа вылетает с ошибкой по завершению. Срабатывают деструкторы.

Но этот пример практически хрестоматиен и на многих ресурсах приводится именно такая реализация.
(Прим. при создании объектов в main через Class *obj = new Class работа программы завершается корректно.)

Что я упустил? Буду рад вашей помощи. Сейчас пишу маленькую библиотеку Img, соотв. стопор на этом моменте.

Спасибо. Пример условный:

```
class SomeClass {
private:
    unsigned char* data;
    int size;
public:
    /* cTor */
    SomeClass() : data(nullptr), size(0) {}
    SomeClass(int arrSize) : data(nullptr), size(arrSize) {
        data = new unsigned char[size];
    }

    /* Copy cTor */
    SomeClass(const SomeClass &obj) : data(nullptr), size(obj.size) {
        data = new unsigned char[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) data[i] = obj.data[i];
    }

    /* Operator = overload */
    SomeClass &operator =(const SomeClass &obj) {
        if (this == &obj) { return *this; }
        delete[] data;
        size = obj.size;
        data = new unsigned char[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) data[i] = obj.data[i];
        return *this;
    }

    /* dTor */
    ~SomeClass() {
        if(data) delete[] data;
    }
};

// ------------------------------------------------

int main() {

    SomeClass A(1);
    SomeClass B(A);
    SomeClass C;

    C = A;

    A.~SomeClass();
    B.~SomeClass();
    C.~SomeClass();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Никакого отношения к конструктору копирования и оператору присваивания данная проблема не имеет. Зачем вы вызываете деструкторы вручную?

Comment: AnT, спасибо за ответ. А как быть в ситуации, когда объект необходимо разрушить (высвободить память). Например идёт постоянное последовательное чтение картинок с диска, обработка и запись. Причём желательно после очередного цикла высвободить память.
Возможно конечно это сделать методом класса (A.Clear()... >  Clear(delete[] data; data = nullptr;)).
Но правильно ли это?
Зачем, тогда деструктор оформлен как метод? А не как внутр. механизм разрушения.

Comment: Так а почему бы не реализовать "внутр. механизм разрушения" как метод? В чем вы видите несоответствие?

Comment: Либо я могу регулировать это создавая экземпляр в каком то блоке с локальной областью видимости, а по завершении выйти из этого блока (видимости) и тем самым разрушу объект автоматом?

IF (Условие) LOOP ---> Img a(Загружаем картинку) ---> /* Что то делаем с картинкой */ ---> a.Clear(Очищаем ресурсы в экземпляре класса)
LOOP AWAY.

P.S конечно я всё это проверяю в коде, прежде чем спрашивать, просто  возникают некот. непонятки. Например код в начале топика работает прекрасно через содание Class *obj = new Class. И к крашу приложения при выходе это не приводит.

Comment: @imluckyike Если вы создаете указатель на экземпляр объекта `Class *obj = new Class`, то при выходе указателя из области видимости никаких действий не происходит, так как у простого указателя тривиальный деструктор. А вместо краша вы получаете утечку памяти, так как объект, созданный посредством вызова оператора `new` должен быть разрушен вызовом оператора `delete`, а не вызовом деструктора вручную.

Comment: AnT и VTT спасибо большое за помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы сначала зачем-то вызываете деструктор класса вручную `A.~SomeClass();`, а затем он автоматически вызывается второй раз при выходе переменной `A` из области видимости. Проверка `if(data)` в деструкторе лишена смысла.

Comment: VTT, спасибо. Да действительно конструкция if(data) не имеет смысла. Во всяком случае статический анализатор напоминает об этом всегда. Но!
Если я не вызываю деструктор вручную, а память освободить нужно (этот экземпляр отработал своё) могу это сделать методом A.Clear()... > Clear(delete[] data; data = nullptr;)). Но тогда в деструкторе пригодится проверка if(data).
Как тогда должен быть спроектирован (условно) этот класс, чтобы я не напоролся на двойной вызов деструктора для объекта, но при этом имел возможность контролировать расход памяти в приложении?

Comment: @imluckyike Деструктор будет вызываться автоматически при выходе объекта из области видимости, вызывать его вручную не следует. Проверка `if(data)` в любом случае будет бесполезной, так как оператор delete сам проверяет переданный указатель.

Comment: Спасибо!
 В общении понимание приходит быстрее чем после прочтения книги.